# Service worker throwing an net::ERR_FILE_EXISTS error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

```
service-worker.js:1 GET http://localhost:8080/service-worker.js net::ERR_FILE_EXISTS
```

This is the error I get every time I refresh after registering a service worker. I've made sure that the service-worker.js file exists in the root directory. Also the service worker is registered and working fine. But I still keep getting this error. Also I'm working on localhost.

This is my service-worker.js file:

```
console.log("SW startup");

var CACHE_NAME = "my_cache";
var urlsToCache = [
  './',
  './css/style.css',
  './js/script.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request.clone()).then(function(response) {
          console.dir(response);
          console.log('hi');
          cache.put(event.request.clone(), response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```

script.js file:

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    console.log("ServiceWorkers are supported");


    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(function(reg) {
            console.log("ServiceWorker registered ◕‿◕");
            console.dir(reg);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Failed to register ServiceWorker ಠ_ಠ");
            console.dir(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm seeing the same issue. It can safely be ignored.

This bug tracks removing the noise from Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=541797

It should be live starting with Chrome 50.

From thread:

> Improve error code for service worker bailing due to no update found
>
> ServiceWorkerWriteToCacheJob is the URLRequestJob responsible for
>   fetching and writing the updated script. It fails with network error
>   when it wants to abort the update because the new script is the same
>   as the old one.
>
> Currently that results in ERR_FAILED errors appearing in the DevTools
>   console and netlog, which is confusing and hard to debug because that
>   error also occurs for actual network errors. This patch changes the
>   error to FILE_EXISTS, so it's more clear why the job "failed".

Comment: are you saying i let this error come in production code of my site ??///.....also why does this same error not come up in other websites consoles (other websites that have implemented service worker ???)

Comment: @amansatija Facebook shows the error after a few seconds if you keep the console open.

Comment: ya i noticed it , now a days it comes on every site that have implemented service worker ...>!!! even pinterest