# Polymer Starter Kit - ERR_FILE_EXISTS when trying to enable service worker

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, service-worker, polymer-starter-kit

I am trying to follow the instructions from [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit#service-worker) to enable offline support (Service worker) in my polymer starter kit clone.

However, after making the changes in *gulpfile.js*, *index.html* and *elements.html*, I keep getting the following error whenever I refresh the page.
[image]

Also if I change the throttling setting to **offline** in Chrome Developer Tools and refresh, the page comes back with the "Unable to connect to the Internet" message so clearly the caching isn't working.

Is there anything else that I need to do?

**Update:** Just decoded the url (i.e. http://localhost:5000/bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-register.html&clientsClaim=true&skipWaiting=true&version=1.0) in the error message and ran it in Chrome and got a **404** error. If I remove everything after .html then the file can be found though.

Comment: `ERR_FILE_EXISTS` might be a dup of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328579/service-worker-throwing-an-neterr-file-exists-error) - apparently this is just an alarming way Chrome reports _hey - the service worker script did not change - eveything is still OK_ condition

Comment: Thanks @pirxpilot, this might be it but still doesn't explain why when I turn off the internet the page goes down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and turned out it's because the `platinum-sw-cache` is set to `disabled` in the dev development, which means service worker will not work if you run

> gulp serve

So to test the PSK offline, you need to call

> gulp serve:dist

You can also ignore that `ERR_FILE_EXISTS` error as explained by @pirxpilot.